# Not getting response from the server during ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I ran an Ajax call but i don't get any response from the server when i set the set
dataType: 'json'  but when i set the  dataType: ''  i get a response. Also when i try to JSON.parse
my response i get an error.

This is the response in my console log when ( dataType: ''):
{"name":"ola","redirect":"port.html","is_logged_in":true}

I want to be able to access (response.name = ola) in my Javascript that's why i tried setting (dataType:'json') but it's not working also with the json.parse when (dataType: '')

**This is my PHP Script**

```
$fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$details = $_POST['message'];


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ){
   // Always return in json format 
   // header('Content-Type: application/json');
   
    
   $return = [];


    
    $findUser = $con->prepare("SELECT fullname from olaweb WHERE email = :email LIMIT 1 ");
    $findUser->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $findUser->execute();




    # Check if the user exit already
    

    if($findUser->rowCount() == 1){
      # user exist
      $return['error'] = "You already have an account";
      $return['is_logged_in'] = false;
   }

   else{
      #user doesn't exist 

      $addUser = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO olaweb (email,fullname,details) VALUES (:email,:fullname,:details)");  
      $addUser->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $addUser->bindParam(':fullname', $fullname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
       $addUser->bindParam(':details',$details, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $addUser->execute();
      
      
   $return['name'] = "ola";
   $return['redirect'] = "port.html";
   $return['is_logged_in'] = true;
   
  
}
//ob_start();

//ob_end_clean();
echo json_encode($return,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); exit;
}
else {
   // Die. Kill the script. Redirect the user. Do something regardless.
   exit('Invalid URL');
}
```

**This is my Javascript code**

```
$("button").click(function(event){

event.preventDefault();

   $.ajax({
    method:"POST",
    url:"poort.php",
    data:$("#inboxForm").serialize(),
    dataType:'json',
    async:true,
    success:  function(response){

    alert(response);
    alert(response.name)

  **your text**  console.log(typeof(response))
    },
    error: function(error){
      alert(error);
     }
  })
```

I have been trying to debug this for weeks I will be so glad if i can get a valid solution to it

Comment: If you get a response when the `dataType` attribute is omitted simply remove it. I believe jQuery is smart enough to figure out the response anyway so you should easily be able to process the json response

Comment: You should do `console.log(response)` instead of `alert(response)` since `alert()` can't properly show contents of objects. You have multiple `alert()` and `console.log()` in your code, which you never mention what they output, so it's a bit unclear atm. JSON.parse() will throw an error (you should always post any error messages as well) if the response already is an object though.

Comment: Please explain all output from the above code (alerts and consoles) in your different attempts (when does it output what) and what error did `JSON.parse()` throw, in what exact situation?

Comment: Remove `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` from your PHP code, and go without it. Or better yet, replace it with `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`. Then, in the front-end part of your code, go with `try { data = JSON.parse(data); } catch (err) { console.log(err); }`

Comment: @M.Eriksson when i set the dataType to json i don't get any response at all so the alert() doesn't yield anything on my browser. Also when i set the dataType to " " i get a response but i can't JSON.parse my response, it says error in my console ( unexpected character at line 1 ) also
console.log(typeof(response)) displays string not an object

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius i can't JSON,parse() my response that's the problem i am having, it displays  ( unexpected character at line 1 )  also console.log(typeof(response)) displays string not an object. 
This is the response i get in my console from the server {"name":"ola","redirect":"port.html","is_logged_in":true}

Comment: If you get unexpected character at line 1, it means it's not valid JSON. Most commonly, something else gets outputted before/after you echo the json in PHP (which is most likely why it fails when you set dataType to json as well). In your browsers development tools, go to the network tab, make the ajax request and check exactly what the response from the server is. If you can't see anything strange (anything other than the serialized json), count the string length and compare it with the content length of the response body (to see if there are any invisible characters returned)

Comment: @M.Eriksson I didn't see any strange character in there, it was exactly the same response, this: {"name":"ola","redirect":"port.html","is_logged_in":true}

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the JSON_PRETTY_PRINT , it is not needed

So change

```
echo json_encode($return,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); exit;
```

to

```
echo json_encode($return); exit;
```

So the following code works (tested : fully working)

[DEMO](http://www.createchhk.com/SOanswers/subr/test2a.php)

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.js"
  integrity="sha256-nQLuAZGRRcILA+6dMBOvcRh5Pe310sBpanc6+QBmyVM="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form id=inboxForm>
<input name=test>
</form>

<input type=button id=xbutton value="GO">

<script>
$("#xbutton").click(function(event){

//alert("1");
event.preventDefault();

   $.ajax({
    method:"POST",
    url:"poort.php",
    data:$("#inboxForm").serialize(),
    dataType:'json',
    async:true,
    success:  function(response){

//    alert(response);
    alert(response.name)
//  **your text**  console.log(typeof(response))
    },
    error: function(error){
      alert(error);
     }
  })

})

</script>
```

For **poort.php** :

```
<?php
//other code doing database processing

 $return = array();

 $return['name'] = "ola";
 $return['redirect'] = "port.html";
 $return['is_logged_in'] = true;
   
echo json_encode($return); exit;

?>
```

Comment: Yes it finally worked thank you , i can see my response in the network section of my dev tools but my javascript doesn't alert it. That's the problem i am having now

Comment: console.log(response) doesn't work either but i can see my response in the network section of my devTools only.  Pls what can i do to debug this

Comment: Also it alert [Object object] instead of the actual response,

Comment: Please copy and paste the two files I provided in your server (the HTML and poort.php), then see whether you see "ola" when you click the "GO" button. After that, compare the code with your own code to see what is/are causing your problems.